# Axios Intercerptors Headers

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

I have a very "strange" error.
I'm adding an interceptor in my axios and adding a new "header", below an example..

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {  
    config.headers['X-Panel-Host'] = document.location.hostname;
    
    return config;
});
```

After I added this new header, I started having the "CORS ERROR" problem, and so far I wasn't having it, however, I added mine in the backend (PHP) with the authorization as below.

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");    
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, X-Panel-Host, X-Host");
```

However, I still get a return in the CORS api, if I remove the line that contains "X-PANEL-HOST" the api works again, what did I forget to do?

Comment: what request method fails according to the console? i think you should also add `HEAD` in your Allow-Methods.